# Initialize an array of int with a range of numbers

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to initialize an array of int and populate it with a range of numbers:

`return new int[].Populate(30,50);`

So then I would have an array with 30, 31, 32, 33... - 50

Comment: The question shouldn't be closed. Initializing an array is not the same as creating a sequence.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Range()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) to e.g. return an array of 21 integers starting at 30:

```
return Enumerable.Range(30, 21).ToArray();
```

Comment: You need to extend the count to 21 (it includes the starting number).

Comment: Fixed - considered OPs problem more of an example

Answer (score 26):

Use Enumerable.Range

```
var array = Enumerable.Range(30, 21).ToArray();
```

This will result in a sequence of 21 values starting at 30. Simply put, you get your `{ 30 ... 50 }` array.

Comment: Is this as fast as a for loop?

Comment: @SamStriano possibly; why don't you try it and see.

Comment: @phoog If somebody already knows the answer, it will save him some time to set up a project to test it

Answer (score 14):

Using a for loop is actually faster than using `Enumerable.Range().ToArray()`

I measured it for creating an array of 1 000 000 elements.

`int[] array = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToArray();` takes 9ms, while creating an array `int[] array2 = new int[1000000];` and filling it in a for loop took only 3ms.

Comment: This seems not to be the case anymore. My measurement of Enumerable.Range().ToArray() of 100 000 000 elements took around 1170 ms, and filling the same amount of elements in `new int[]` in a loop took around 6900 ms.